# Using @ResponseObject with Quarkus resteasy reactive client

Tags: quarkus, resteasy, quarkus-rest-client, quarkus-reactive

I have been trying to use `@ResponseObject` from RestEasy in Quarkus RestEasy Reactive client, [jboss documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/5.0.9.Final/userguide/html/ch50.html#Response_proxies)  states that annotating the interface with `@ResponseObject` would allow me to use the response proxies feature but Quarkus client doesn't seems to know how to process the annotation.

Calling the client raises an exception

```
org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.ClientWebApplicationException: Received: 'HTTP 400 Bad Request' when invoking: Rest Client method: 'demo.resteasy.ExampleClient#responseObjectHello'

    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.RestClientRequestContext.unwrapException(RestClientRequestContext.java:186)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.handleException(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:326)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:175)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualRunnable.run(SlowContextualRunnable.java:19)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSwitchToRequestContextRestHandler$1$1.handle(ClientSwitchToRequestContextRestHandler.java:38)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSwitchToRequestContextRestHandler$1$1.handle(ClientSwitchToRequestContextRestHandler.java:35)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:277)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:259)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$runOnContext$0(EventLoopContext.java:43)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `demo.resteasy.WithResponseObject` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1915)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:414)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1360)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:274)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1481)
    at io.quarkus.rest.client.reactive.jackson.runtime.serialisers.ClientJacksonMessageBodyReader.readFrom(ClientJacksonMessageBodyReader.java:53)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.ClientReaderInterceptorContextImpl.proceed(ClientReaderInterceptorContextImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.ClientSerialisers.invokeClientReader(ClientSerialisers.java:160)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.RestClientRequestContext.readEntity(RestClientRequestContext.java:198)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientResponseCompleteRestHandler.mapToResponse(ClientResponseCompleteRestHandler.java:104)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientResponseCompleteRestHandler.handle(ClientResponseCompleteRestHandler.java:35)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientResponseCompleteRestHandler.handle(ClientResponseCompleteRestHandler.java:31)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.invokeHandler(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:231)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
    ... 14 more
```

The Client

```java
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "api")
public interface ExampleClient {

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    String typedHello();

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response responseHello();

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    WithResponseObject responseObjectHello();


}
```

The Response Object annotated model

```java
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.Body;
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.ResponseObject;
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.Status;

@ResponseObject
public interface WithResponseObject {
    @Status
    int status();

    @Body
    String body();
}
```

POM <quarkus.platform.version>3.6.6</quarkus.platform.version>

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-core-spi</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Does Quarkus support `@ResponseObject`?

Comment: It does not. Can you open an issue explaining the why you want to use it and asking for the feature? Thanks